# Activate action by reaching a score

Tags: swift

How can I set an action by reaching a specific score? for example a pop up or an animation.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var ScoreLabel: UILabel!

    var taps = 0
    var highscore = 200

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if let storedTaps = defaults.objectForKey("key") as? Int {
            self.taps = storedTaps
            setLabel(storedTaps)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func ScoreButton(sender: UIButton) {

        taps += 1
        setLabel(taps)
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setInteger(taps, forKey: "key")

    }

    func setLabel(taps:Int) {
        ScoreLabel.text = "Taps: \(taps)"
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is implement `didSet` for the `taps` variable, which fires every time you set the value of `taps`, and then check what value it was set to.

Like this:

```
var taps = 0 {
   didSet {
      if taps == 5 {
          print("You have reaches 5 taps !!")
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: when I insert that into my code there is an error which says "expected declaration" what can I da to fix that?

Comment: override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        
        var taps = 0 {
            didSet {
                if taps == 5 {
                    print("You have reaches 5 taps !!")
                }
            }

Comment: I pasted it into my didRecieveMemoryWarning

Comment: Place it in the place of your current `var taps = 0`